# Mongo query with sort inner field returns lesser results than in the collection

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Mongodb contains a collection that has following objects,

Objects with `lastTrip` :

```
   {
        "usage" : 0,
        "lastMaintenanceDate" : NumberLong(1572600811104),
        "lastTrip" : {
            "direction" : "DOWN",
             "startLevel" : 5
             }
  }
```

Objects without `lastTrip`:

```
{
            "usage" : 0,
            "lastMaintenanceDate" : NumberLong(1572600811104),

    }
```

And following query is used to retrieve data with sorting,

```
Query one:
    db.getCollection('some_collection').find({}).sort({"lastTrip.startLevel":1})
```

This only returns objects with the field `lastTrip`, even though collection contains objects without that field.

This issue is causing me getting wrong count on following query,

```
Query two:
    db.getCollection('some_collection').find({}).sort({"lastTrip.startLevel":1}).count()
```

Expected result:

```
Query one > 20 documents
Query two > 20
```

Actual result:

```
Query one > 15 documents
Query two > 20
```

What is the proper way of querying(for query one) to get objects without the field `lastTrip` as well?

Comment: Please share collection

Comment: added two types of documents that contain in the collection.

Comment: Please share collection at jsoneditor online

Comment: There is a query operator [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/index.html) to match documents which contains the field.